# Why composer update updates symfony to 2.5 but it's "symfony/symfony": "~2.4"?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

Maybe I'm totally wrong about how Composer works, but given the following `composer.json` (part of Symfony, with some added requirements not shown here):

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
    "doctrine/orm": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/dbal": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "dev-master",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    // my requirements here
}
```

When I run `composer update` I get symfony/symfony 2.5 instead of ~2.4 (that is AFAIK 2.4.1, 2.4.2, etc).

Comment: Same question here. I add to update my code to 2.5 in my prod env. Was quite weird.

Comment: The question should be as well: Why not? Always ask from both directions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`~2.4` is equivalent of `>=2.4,<3.0`. If you would like to stay with `2.4.x` branch you would have to use `2.4.*`.

You can read more about version numbers on Composer's documentation pages: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#package-versions

Comment: My mistake... I was convinced what ~2.4 was equivalent to 2.4.*.

Comment: Just for the record: the equivalent to 2.4.* in ~ syntax is ~2.4.0